# Python requests hidden authentication key

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to pull values from a website using python requests but once I do a post request to the URL that contains the data I don't get what I expect. I am assuming the reason for this is because the cookie contains a session ID as well as a "what seems to be" a hidden Auth ID.

my code:
'''

```
login_url = "https://www.aucampelectronics.co.za/Login.aspx/SecureLogin"
login_payload = {'userName' : 'user', 'password' : 'pass', 'returnUrl' : './#Home'}
login_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'}
site_url = "https://www.aucampelectronics.co.za/secure/Service.aspx/GetSite"
site_payload = "{'siteId' : 182}"

s = requests.session()
r = s.post(login_url, headers=login_headers, data=login_payload, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.cookies)
site = s.post(site_url, headers=login_headers, data=site_payload)
print(site.text)
```

'''

The hidden Cookie unfortunately does not show up when I print the cookie and I see just the session id.

[Login URL Headers 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf4Of.png)

[Login URL Headers 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdE2L.png)

[Site URL Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4jbk.png)

[Requests payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgcx3.png)

Above I have attached Images so that the headers can be seen in these headers you can see there is a hidden Auth set-cookie then they create the cookie with that set cookie.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the request payloads? You can block the user and pw but I suspect that there is some kind of hidden id that is injected into a form input field and that is passed in the body of the form submission. If that is the case, you'll need to extract this from the HTML, it wouldn't show in your cookies or anything. Which makes sense, since this is probably like a one time use authenticating id

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the requests payload hope this helps